# Moving content form local storage to OS file system

Tags: html, api, browser, filesystems, local-storage

I’m looking to implement Drag and Drop solution, than store the web page content and assets in the local storage using filesystem API. 
My problem is that I need to move the files I’ve stored in the local storage to OS file system. 
Would be interesting to hear few implementation for this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has a File System API included that allows you to read, write and create files in a secured virtual file system that are also domain-specific (no file crossing with other domains).
If you are just trying to store contents and assets for offline viewing, you can just whip up a Manifest Cache. I see no need for local storage, or drag and drop, or File System API, because these are very different tools for very different needs. Anyway, if you would still like to use File System API, [check out this page from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File_API/File_System_API).

Angela